# Data Bar calculated from another cell (Conditional Formatting)

Tags: excel

In Excel 2016, I've been using conditional formatting's 'Data Bars' to make progress bars in a task register. I don't enough reputation to post an image, but imagine a table like this with data bars in the right column:

```
+---------+----------+
| Project | Progress |
+---------+----------+
| Task 1  | 40%      |
| Task 2  | 20%      |
| Task 3  | 100%     |
| Task 4  | 80%      |
+---------+----------+
```

Would it be possible to have the data bar display in the Project column instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, data bars need to get their data from the cell in which they exist.

However, a couple workarounds/alternate methods:

- You could **overlay a bar chart**, removing all the backgrounds, borders, axes and gridlines, and setting the bar colour to be 60%+ transparent.

  [image: img]
  <sup>([Source](https://superuser.com/a/829554/774713))</sup>
- You could use conditional formatting to display a **solid color or gradient fill** in the alternate cells.

  [image: img]